# Check whether a tree is a binary search tree using inorder

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, binary-search-tree

```
int* inorder(node* root)
{
    //Dynamically Created array as we are required to pass array into main function
    int* arr=new int[100];
    int i=0;
    if(root==NULL)
    return 0;
    inorder(root->left);
    arr[i]=root->data;
    i++;
    inorder(root->right);
    return arr;
}
```

We are required to check whether the tree is Bst or not using Inorder traversal.If the data present in the array are sorted then it is Bst.After passing the array in main() we will check whether the array is sorted or not but **when i checked the content of the array it comes out to be a garbage value**
and tree always comes out to be not a Bst for input tree that is bst

```
int main()
{
    node* root= newNode(6);
    root->left= newNode(4);
    root->right= newNode(8);
    root->left->left= newNode(3);
    root->left->right= newNode(5);
    root->right->left= newNode(7);
    root->right->right= newNode(9);
    int* ptr=inorder(root);
    if(is_sorted(ptr,ptr+7))
    cout<<"Tree is Binary search tree: "<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"Tree is not a binary search tree: "<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You have plenty of chances of memory leaks, especially since you don't do anything with the pointers returned by the recursive calls.

Comment: As for your problem, is the array you allocate supposed to be used and shared by *all* calls to the `inorder` function? Then besides that it's *not* shared in any way, you don't even initialize it. And really, stop using `new[]` when you have access to `std::vector`.

Comment: vector<int> inorder(node* root)
{
 vector<int> v;
 if(root==NULL)
 return; //what to return if the root is NULL
 inorder(root->left);
 v.push_back(root->data)
 inorder(root->right);
 return v;
}

Comment: It's no surprise that your array contains garbage. When do you set the value of any element in the array other than `arr[0]` (more precisely, `arr[i]` with `i` equal to `0`)?

Answer (score 0):

Using a vector is unnecessary here. Determining whether a tree is a binary search tree does not require any extra memory apart from the stack for the recursive calls.

If you define a separate inorder tree traversal algorithm that makes the implementation almost trivial:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node *left, *right;
};

template<class T, class F>
bool traverse_inorder(Node<T> const* tree, F&& f) {
    return !tree || (
           traverse_inorder(tree->left, std::forward<F>(f))
        && f(tree->value)
        && traverse_inorder(tree->right, std::forward<F>(f))
        );
}

template<class T, class Pred>
bool is_bst(Node<T> const* tree, Pred&& pred) {
    T const* p = 0;
    return traverse_inorder(tree, [&p, &pred](T const& next) {
        T const* prev = p;
        p = &next;
        return !prev || !pred(next, *prev);
    });
}

template<class T>
bool is_bst(Node<T> const* tree) {
    return is_bst(tree, std::less<T>{});
}

int main() {
    // bst tree:
    //       33
    //   20      35
    // 10  30
    Node<int> n1{10}, n3{30}, n2{20, &n1, &n3}, n5{35}, n4{33, &n2, &n5};
    auto tree = &n4;

    std::cout << is_bst(tree) << '\n'; // Outputs 1.

    // Break bst property.
    n4.value = 25;
    std::cout << is_bst(tree) << '\n'; // Outputs 0.
}
```

---

To convert a tree into a vector using inorder traversal you can use the following function:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> inorder_to_vector(Node<T> const* tree) {
    std::vector<T> v;
    traverse_inorder(tree, [&v](T const& t) {
        v.push_back(t);
        return true;
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Using inorder i want to form a vector and that vector i will pass in main () to check whether it is sorted or not if it is sorted then it is Bst.I want to do it with vector

Comment: @Gaurav1527 Added a conversion function for you.